# ClassNotFoundException in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, classnotfoundexception

A `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown during startup of Tomcat despite that the missing class is located in a jar file present in `webapps\myWebApp\WEB-INF\lib`

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or NetBeans or any other IDE ?

Comment: Actually its just a plain grails war file being deployed in tomcat. All needed jar files are packaged during build and stored in the WEB-INF\lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your jar file to your build path.

Right click on the project, go to `Properties -> Build Path -> Add jar files`

or Right click `project -> Java Build Path -> Add jar file to project`.

The option to add jar file to build path will depend on your IDE.

Comment: It's a grails app, build from command line: grails war. The "missing" class is present inside a jar file in the WEB-INF\lib folder